# Custom callback passportjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an ordering form, the user needs to signup before he/she can order, so I can create an account then process the order like this.

```
router.post('/project/new', passport.authenticate('local-signup'), function(req, res) {

  gateway.customer.find(req.user.id, function(err, customer) {

    if(customer) {

      // method for a customer inside the vault

    } else {

      // add a non existing customer to vault

    }

  });

});
```

The problem is if someone is logged in already and wants to make an order. I need to check if they are logged in, if they are then I can proceed with the order, if they are NOT then I need to authenticate then log them in.

So something like this makes sense to me.

```
//prefer this!!
router.post('/project/new', function(req, res) {

  if(req.user) {

    // do stuff for existing logged in user

  } else {

    // user is NOT logged in need passport
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {

      // do stuff for new user

    })(req, res, next);

  }

});
```

The problem with that is I get `next is not defined`, I see in the passportjs docs Jared uses this custom callback inside a `get` route.

Can someone help me make a custom callback? Does anyone have a better strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined, because you haven't defined it, you can define it as such:

```
router.post('/project/new', function(req, res, next){
 // rest of your code here
}
```

Though in your case, you're better off moving your authentication logic to separate middleware, something like this:

```
router.post('/project/new', 
  function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
      next();
    } else {

      // do whatever to create a new user

    }
  },
  function(req, res) {
    // this function will be called after your auth logic is done
    // at this point, your req.user should be populated, respond with an error status if for some reason its not
    if (!req.user) return res.send(500);

    // the rest of your logic here

  }
);
```

Comment: Looks good, I never understood the purpose of next, thanks for helping. Let me try this!